# How to reindex a a pandas dataframe by date range without deleting values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

**Background:**

I have the following data frame downloaded with pyodbc with dates between 1999 and 2015:

```
CEISales.head(10)
Out[194]: 
   Order_DateC   RegionC     SalesC
0  2014-01-30  Domestic    3530.00
1  2011-10-11  Domestic     136.00
2  1999-01-13  Domestic      30.00
3  1999-01-13  Domestic   55615.00
4  1999-01-13  Domestic     440.00
5  1999-01-13  Domestic      94.00
6  1999-01-05  Domestic     612.00
7  1999-01-14  Domestic    1067.00
8  1999-01-14  Domestic   26345.05
9  1999-01-15  Domestic  161858.72
```

I then filtered the data for all dates greater than 2010-01-01 and sorted by ascending dates:

```
CEIFilter = CEISales[CEISales['Order_DateC'] > '2010-01-01']

CEITest = CEIFilter.sort('Order_DateC')

CEITest.head(5)
Out[199]: 
      Order_DateC   RegionC   SalesC
18156  2010-01-04   Foreign    450.0
18155  2010-01-04  Domestic   1990.4
18154  2010-01-04  Domestic  37477.0
18152  2010-01-04  Domestic      0.0
18153  2010-01-04  Domestic    783.0
```

I then created a date index with values between 2010-01-01 and today with pandas's date_range function:

```
date_index = pd.date_range(start='2010-01-01', end='2015-12-23' , freq='d')
```

And re-indexed the data frame

```
CEIFinal= CEITest.reindex(date_index)
```

My problem is that when I re-indexed the data frame, all of the data was deleted:

```
CEIFinal.head(5)
Out[206]: 
            Order_DateC RegionC  SalesC
2010-01-01         NaT     NaN     NaN
2010-01-02         NaT     NaN     NaN
2010-01-03         NaT     NaN     NaN
2010-01-04         NaT     NaN     NaN
2010-01-05         NaT     NaN     NaN
```

From the original filtered data frame you can see that there were transactions on the 2010-04-01

```
CEITest[CEITest['Order_DateC'] == '2010-01-04']
Out[210]: 
      Order_DateC   RegionC   SalesC
18156  2010-01-04   Foreign    450.0
18155  2010-01-04  Domestic   1990.4
18154  2010-01-04  Domestic  37477.0
18152  2010-01-04  Domestic      0.0
18153  2010-01-04  Domestic    783.0
```

**Question**
How do I re-index this data frame with this date range and keep all of the original values? I am trying to create a common index on several different data frames from difference databases to add together into an aggregated data frame. Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're re-indexing by a DatetimeIndex when the index is not a DatetimeIndex:

```
      Order_DateC   RegionC   SalesC
18156  2010-01-04   Foreign    450.0
18155  2010-01-04  Domestic   1990.4
18154  2010-01-04  Domestic  37477.0
18152  2010-01-04  Domestic      0.0
18153  2010-01-04  Domestic    783.0
```

hence the NaNs and NaTs.

Perhaps you want to make `Order_DateC` the index:

```
df = df.set_index("Order_DateC")
```

then to [*resample*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

If you reindex, you're going to lose the rows with duplicate dates.

Comment: Would I resample the date_index or CEITest first? Could you give me an example of how to resample these data frames? Thanks for your help Andy!

Comment: @Andrew this is *instead* of `date_index`. Once you have a DatetimeIndex you can do `df.resample("d", how="sum")` or similar. Look up how to resample separately. It's similar to a groupby, you can also do `df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper("d"), "RegionC"]).sum()` etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need set index from column `Order_DateC` before reindex:

```
CEITest = CEITest.set_index('Order_DateC')
```

And final you can check `notnull` values by [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print CEIFinal[CEIFinal.notnull().any(axis=1)]

             RegionC  SalesC
2011-10-11  Domestic     136
2014-01-30  Domestic    3530
```

All together:

```
print CEISales
  Order_DateC   RegionC     SalesC
0  2014-01-30  Domestic    3530.00
1  2011-10-11  Domestic     136.00
2  1999-01-13  Domestic      30.00
3  1999-01-13  Domestic   55615.00
4  1999-01-13  Domestic     440.00
5  1999-01-13  Domestic      94.00
6  1999-01-05  Domestic     612.00
7  1999-01-14  Domestic    1067.00
8  1999-01-14  Domestic   26345.05
9  1999-01-15  Domestic  161858.72

CEIFilter = CEISales[CEISales['Order_DateC'] > '2010-01-01']
CEITest = CEIFilter.sort_values('Order_DateC')
print CEITest
  Order_DateC   RegionC  SalesC
1  2011-10-11  Domestic     136
0  2014-01-30  Domestic    3530

#set index to datetimeindex
CEITest = CEITest.set_index('Order_DateC')
print CEITest
              RegionC  SalesC
Order_DateC                  
2011-10-11   Domestic     136
2014-01-30   Domestic    3530

date_index = pd.date_range(start='2010-01-01', end='2015-12-23' , freq='d')
```

```
CEIFinal= CEITest.reindex(date_index)

print CEIFinal.head()
           RegionC  SalesC
2010-01-01     NaN     NaN
2010-01-02     NaN     NaN
2010-01-03     NaN     NaN
2010-01-04     NaN     NaN
2010-01-05     NaN     NaN
```

There can be many `Nat` and `NaN`, check data:

```
print CEIFinal[CEIFinal.notnull().any(axis=1)]
             RegionC  SalesC
2011-10-11  Domestic     136
2014-01-30  Domestic    3530
```

In the end you can set index name and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) index - column name is index name:

```
CEIFinal.index.name = 'CEIFinal'
CEIFinal = CEIFinal.reset_index()
print CEIFinal.head()
   CEIFinal RegionC  SalesC
0 2010-01-01     NaN     NaN
1 2010-01-02     NaN     NaN
2 2010-01-03     NaN     NaN
3 2010-01-04     NaN     NaN
4 2010-01-05     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for the response jezrael. I tried your code and print CEIFinal.head() returned an empty data frame.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you can check both indexes: `print CEITest.index` and `print CEIFinal.index` (before reset index)

Comment: Ir returns with this sample: `DatetimeIndex(['2011-10-11', '2014-01-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'Order_DateC', freq=None)
DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-01', '2010-01-02', '2010-01-03', '2010-01-04',
               '2010-01-05', '2010-01-06', '2010-01-07', '2010-01-08',
               '2010-01-09', '2010-01-10',
               ...
               '2015-12-14', '2015-12-15', '2015-12-16', '2015-12-17',
               '2015-12-18', '2015-12-19', '2015-12-20', '2015-12-21',
               '2015-12-22', '2015-12-23'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=2183, freq='D')`